# why won't anyting append to data?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function for handling uploading files to an API, I have narrowed the problem down to the formData(at data variable) I try to create seems to get nothing. The selectedFiles the function loops through is always full with one or more files(checked using console log). Whenever I try to console.log(data) it has none of the files in it from selectedFiles even though I append them, so I keep just sending empty formData to my API. I am not appending the data correctly maybe???

here is the fileUploader function:

```
const fileUploader = () => {
    const data = new FormData();

    if (selectedFiles) {

      //for loop to loop through the selected files and add them to the form data
      for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
        data.append(selectedFiles[i].name, selectedFiles[i]);
      }

      axios
        .post(
          `http://localhost:3030/api/listings/${listingId}/uploadimages`,
          data,
          {
            headers: {
              accept: 'application/json',
              'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
              'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
            },
          }
        )
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

A form is technically allowed to have many fields with the same name, so multiple calls to append add more same-named fields.

Try this

```
  for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
    data.append("files[]", selectedFiles.files[i]);
  }
```

Comment: This is what I had before at once, but now I get a 'parameter 2 is not of type "Blob", any idea??

Comment: try selectedFiles.files[i] in the second parameter

Comment: Does not work. selectedFile[i] accesses each file correctly.